# ERD 3 tables in 1 relationship

Tags: database, erd

i am having a hard time creating an ERD for my table relationship. I have 4 tables: film, ticket_type, studio, and schedule. The schedule table is a relationship table that contain the primary key from the other three tables as foreign key. The question is how can i picture it in ERD? Something like many-to-many relationship but with 3 table, is it possible to do it like this? The database works fine when i try to create it so i think there's​ no problem in my concept. Thanks in advance.

Edit: forgot to add the ticket_type table is for pricing and type like: 2d,3d,or 4d, i create it like this to avoid redundancy.
One more question, can i add another field to a relationship table? If I remember correctly it should be fine, but just to make sure.

Comment: What is the PK of your schedule table? If it's a composite of FK columns, it's a relationship table, if it's a surrogate key, it's an entity table. Both kinds can have additional attributes.

Comment: The PK is "shedule_id" and it is a relationship table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `schedule` is a relationship, it would be represented as follows on an entity-relationship diagram:

[image: Schedule as a relationship - ER diagram]

Relationships are identified by the keys of the related entities. A table diagram makes this more visible:

[image: Schedule as a relationship - table diagram]

However, if `schedule` is an entity set with relationships to the other 3 entity sets, it would be represented as follows on an ER diagram:

[image: Schedule as an entity set - ER diagram]

If we map every entity set and relationship to its own table, we get the following table diagram:

[image: Schedule as an entity set - table diagram]

However, if we denormalize the relationship tables into the `schedule` table (since they all have the same primary key), our table diagram changes to:

[image: Schedule as an entity set - denormalized table diagram]

Compare this with the first table diagram. While these physical models are very similar, they derive from very different conceptual models. Strictly speaking, I think both "entity table" and "relationship table" are inappropriate for the denormalized `schedule` table. In the network data model, we would call it an associative entity (but that's not the same as associative entities in the ER model).

Finally, relationships can have attributes too:

[image: Relationship attribute - ER diagram]

[image: Relationship attribute - table diagram]

Comment: At first i thought of using the first diagram too, but shouldn't a relationship use a verb? And for the table diagram, I don't need to add a schedule id in the relationship table? I mean if I want to use it for example transaction then i need to use it to determine which schedule i use in the transaction. Or is it just to model it in table diagram, but i still need to create it in the real database?

Comment: The idea that entities = nouns, relationships = verbs is a gross oversimplification. The difference is arbitrary and a lot of complexity in the Entity-Relationship model derives from trying to keep these ideas separate. Whether something is an entity set or a relationship in ER depends on its key, not on how it's named. The relational model simplifies things - fact-oriented modeling is based on the idea that tables represent predicates - sentence forms with placeholders (represented by columns) which can express much more complicated relations than simple verbs.

Comment: Adding a schedule_id changes the conceptual and logical models too - file_id, ticket_type_id and studio_id become dependent attributes instead of being part of the determinant. Without schedule_id, you could use a composite foreign key in your transaction table, and schedule then becomes a relationship in a relationship (what ER calls an associative entity). Alternatively, you can turn schedule into an entity set by adding schedule_id, then add a unique constraint on the combination of the 3 foreign keys. Whether you implement schedule_id or not, make sure your model matches your decision.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think for now i will use schedule_id because i am not really sure how to make the relation of schedule and other table/s that will use its data. I will try to read more about associative entity and develop it from there, can you give me a reference to learn about this topic, relationship​ and erd related material?

Comment: The best place to start with the Entity-Relationship model is Peter Chen's paper `The Entity-Relationship Model - Toward a Unified View of Data`. E.F. Codd's paper `A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Databanks` provides valuable background. Most online references and tutorials tend to mix up entity-relationship and network model concepts, but university sites tend to be a little better.

Comment: Thanks once again, I'll look it up later.

Comment: what is the application you made the diagrams?

Comment: @alien For the ER diagrams, I used Dia. The table diagrams may have been MySQL Workbench or Visual Paradigm.